# Replace last occurrence of .jar in ansible regex_replace

Tags: regex, ansible

How can I replace only the last character of .jar. Below is the sample value for `LIST_jar[0].nameOfJar` and the sample output expected

```
my-firsrt.jar-1.jar           >> my-firsrt.jar-1
my-firsrt-2.0.jar-1.jar       >> my-firsrt-2.0.jar-1
my-firsrt-1.0-jar-1.jar       >> my-firsrt-1.0-jar-1
my-firsrt-jar-1.0-jar-1.jar   >> my-firsrt-jar-1.0-jar-1
my-firsrt-jar-1.0.jar.jar     >> my-firsrt-jar-1.0.jar
my-firsrt-jar-1.0-jar.jar     >> my-firsrt-jar-1.0.jar
```

This is my sample code but it is not working accordingly as it is replacing all the jar value.

```
- name: Replace string
  copy:
    content: "{ name: jack }"
    dest: "{{ directory }}/JAR_LIST/{{ LIST_jar[0].nameOfJar | regex_replace('.jar') }}.log"
```

Comment: Please don't forget to accept (and up-vote) one of the answers if it answers your question.

Comment: sure. will do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Below is my sample code but it is not working accordingly as it is replacing all the jar value.

Correct, because the `.` in regex means "any character." If you just want to replace the literal string `.jar` then don't use regex replace, just use [`replace()`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#replace) which will use the literal characters you provide to it.

Otherwise, if you wish to continue to use regex_replace, then quote that character and also specify that the pattern should only match the end of the string

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ nameOfJar | regex_replace('[.]jar$', '') }}.log"
  vars:
    nameOfJar: my-firsrt-jar-1.0-jar-1.jar
```

We're going to assume the last two of your samples were just copy paste in this question, and that you prefer the `.log` outside the mustaches instead of just including `'.log'` in the replacement position of regex_replace

Comment: hi can i know if i put regex_replace('.jar$') is there any imapct? as i tested this also was showing it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

There are more options. The most simple is *splitext*. More versatile is *split* to manipulate multiple extensions. The filter *regex_replace* is more complex but universal.

---

**splitext**

Use [splitext](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-file-names-and-path-names). For example

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "dest: {{ (item|splitext).0 }}.log"
      loop: "{{ list_jar }}"
```

gives (given the list of filenames is in the variable *list_jar*)

```yaml
  msg: 'dest: my-firsrt.jar-1.log'
  msg: 'dest: my-firsrt-2.0.jar-1.log'
  msg: 'dest: my-firsrt-1.0-jar-1.log'
  msg: 'dest: my-firsrt-jar-1.0-jar-1.log'
  msg: 'dest: my-firsrt-jar-1.0.jar.log'
  msg: 'dest: my-firsrt-jar-1.0-jar.log'
```

---

**split**

The next option is *split*. The task below gives the same results

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "dest: {{ item.split('.')[:-1]|join() }}.log"
      loop: "{{ list_jar }}"
```

---

**regex_replace**

If you want to use *regex_replace* the tasks below give the same results. Either remove the extension and concatenate `.log`

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "dest: {{ item|regex_replace('^(.*)\\.jar$', '\\1') }}.log"
      loop: "{{ list_jar }}"
```

, or replace the extension in the filter

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "dest: {{ item|regex_replace('^(.*)\\.jar$', '\\1.log') }}"
      loop: "{{ list_jar }}"
```

---

To make the code more readable it's a good idea to put the regular expressions into the variables and use [single-quoted style](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2788097). For example

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "dest: {{ item|regex_replace(my_regex, my_replace) }}"
      loop: "{{ list_jar }}"
      vars:
        my_regex: '^(.*)\.jar$'
        my_replace: '\1.log'
```

Comment: hi can i know if i put regex_replace('.jar$') is there any imapct? as i tested this also was showing it accordingly.

Comment: There is no impact in your specific case because all filenames are terminated by the extension ".jar". The dot in the regex matches any character and matches the dot "." in the extension of the filename as well. As a result, the regex matches the extensions of all files. You will see the difference with a filename, for example, "my-firsrt.jar-1-jar ". The extension "-jar" will be matched too. If you want to match a dot "." escape it "\." or put it explicitly as a character "[.]" in the regex. This will declare exactly what you want and avoid confusion when reading the code later.